# Unaccentuate a word for a URL Wiktionary search

Tags: language, url

I use Anki to learn Russian vocabulary. I have been trying to create my own card template with an URL that points towards Wiktionary. The problem is that my words are most often accentuated (because, why not...), and I see that in two links below, with and without accent, only one pings.

[сле́дующий](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%CC%81%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9) versus 
[следующий](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9)

only the second one (unaccentuated) works. I see that the difference in the URL between both symbol chains (what are these %XX anyway ?) is %CC%81, which seems to corresponds to how Firefox understands the presence of this particular accent. Probably for ё it's something else.

I use Ilya Birman's typography keyboard for the accents on my mac, but the link is the same if I copy-paste Wiktionary's сле́дующий from [this page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9), so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The %XX is the way that certain special characters (that are not allowed in URLs) are encoded in URLs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. An example you will see quite often is %20, which is the way the space character will be represented in a URL (with this you can imagine quite well why it is not allowed in a URL).

I'm pretty sure that wiktionary uses the acute accent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent - this is the accent that you are using as well (%CC%81 is the representation of the acute accent - the accent on the ё is not a separate character, so this will not cause any issues).

With all of that in mind, the problem here is simply that the wiktionary urls use the word name, not the word with an accent - this is why your link doesn't work - the page doesn't exist. The link is valid, but the page doesn't exist on wiktionary.org.

You will need to remove the accent from the url (U+0301,    & #769;) - ideally before creating the link. As to how, this depends how you are creating your flashcards.